# Exercism exercise: jasmine-node . - command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, command, jasmine-node

I'm trying to run the first exercise in Exercism. I have followed the readme instructions and installed Homebrew, and then installed the CLI. Everything went fine.

I then typed in the command line to download the first test - Hello World. Again, this worked fine.

The next instruction was

```
Execute the tests with: 

jasmine-node .
```

I assume this is to be typed into Terminal? This is what I've tried and it says 'command not found'. There is no other instructions. I've never even come across Jasmine before. I downloaded jasmine-node separately via npm,

```
npm install jasmine-node -g
```

...but this has still made no difference.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "this has still made no difference", do you mean you are geting the same `command not found` error?

Comment: Apologies this has been resolved. I had my $PATH variable pointing to the wrong folder for my global installs. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's great to hear :) Want to answer your own question below, or maybe delete the question altogether to keep things clean?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this link
http://exercism.io/languages/javascript/installing
It details all the dependencies you need to install
the command that did it for me was 
npm install jasmine-node -g